# How to preview texture nodes by hovering?

Tags: node-editor

How does he achieve seeing the texture by only hovering over each node? https://youtu.be/5TcBWJva9aE?t=144

Comment: Hello :). It's just clever video editing, not a real Blender feature.

Comment: It's relatively expensive compared to other addons but you may be interested in https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview

Comment: @Gorgious I stand corrected, looks really cool :))

Comment: @JachymMichal Hopefully this will be fully integrated at some point in the future :)

Comment: It seems to me to be an expensive and real-estate-intrusive way of doing Node Wrangler's Ctrl-Shift-Click.